# rxjs - observable emits nothing (not completing?)

Tags: angular, group-by, rxjs, toarray

I have an angular 6 app and I originally set up my backend with a rest api, but i'm starting to convert parts to use socket.io.

When I return the data from my rest api the following works:

```
this.http.get(api_url + '/versions/entity/' + entityId).pipe(
  mergeMap((versions:IVersion[]) => versions),
  groupBy((version:IVersion) => version.type),
  mergeMap(group => group.pipe(
    toArray(),
    map(versions=> {
      return {
        type: group.key,
        versions: versions
      }
    }),
    toArray()
  )),
  reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat(v), [])
);
```

The express route:

```
router.get('/entity/:entityId', (req, res) => {
  const entityId = req.params.entityId;

  Version.getVersionsByEntity(entityId, (err, versions) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({success: false, msg: err});
    } else {
      res.json(versions);
    }
  });
});
```

Which gets the data from my mongo database with mongoose:

```
export function getVersionsByEntity(entityId, callback) {
  console.log('models/version - get versions by entity');

  Version.find({'entity.entityId': entityId})
          .exec(callback);
}
```

However when I make the exact same call but with socket.io the observable doesn't return anything. I'm guessing its because it never completes? Does an http call send a 'complete' message when the data is successfully transferred?

The sockets are sent from this service:

```
getVersionsByEntity(entityId): Observable<IVersion[]> {
    // create observable to list to refreshJobs message
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this._socketService.socket.on('versionsByEntity', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
    });

    this._socketService.event('versionsByEntity', entityId);

    return <Observable<IVersion[]>> observable;
  }
```

Which calls the same mongoose function from the server.

The observable returned from (socket) service does actually contain data, it's only once I add the `toArray()` functions that it never prints anything when I subscribe..

Could someone help me fix this and also explain the theory behind this? Is it not completing? Does http send a 'completed' message with Angular?

EDIT: I've created a simple stackblitz which is doing what I want but I want to remove the take(1) from the _dataService since I may want to update the data so I want to keep the observable open - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-toarray-problem

EDIT 2: I'm close by replacing toArray with the scan operator but it seems to be emitting twice for the array. reduce() emits the correct data but seems to only emit on complete (like toArray) so its no better - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-toarray-problem-tpeguu

Answer (score 1):

Handling event streams is a little bit different. I have tried to propose some code bellow:

```
getVersionsByEntity(entityId): Observable<IVersion[]> {
    return defer(() => {
        this._socketService.event('versionsByEntity', entityId);

        return fromEvent(this._socketService.socket, 'versionsByEntity')
            .pipe(take(1))
    }) as Observable<IVersion[]>;
}
```

The main idea is to wrap everything in `defer` which will make the Observable lazy and only call `socketService.event` when it's subscribed (your original implementation is eager by calling `socketService.event` right away). Having implementation eager can have unintended consequences - it's easy to miss event if the Observable is subscribed too late.

I also suggest using `fromEvent` Observable factory - which handles event listener setup and tear down.

Finally to complete the Observable after first emission I've added `take(1)` - this will limit the number of emissions to 1 and unsubscribe the Observable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that all makes sense, I’ll try and implement your suggestions as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @m1ch4ls said, you have to consider how `toArray` works. `toArray` transforms all data notified by an Observable into an array of such data. In order for this to work, the Observable has to complete.

An Observable returned by the Angular http client completes always after the first notification, and therefore `toArray` works. A socket.io stream completes when it is closed, so using `toArray` on such a stream may have the effect of never getting any value out of the Observable in case the stream is not closed.

On the other hand, if you want to close the stream after one notification, which is what happens if you use `take(1)` then you better consider stay with http requests. Socket streams are thought to be sort of long living channels so it does not fit their nature if you have to close them always after one message has been transmitted.

**UPDATED VERSION after comment**

Here is the code that works without `take`

```
 getData() {
    return this._dataService.getVersions().pipe(
      map(
        (versions: Array<any>) => versions.reduce(
          (acc, val) => {
            const versionGroup = (acc.find(el => el.type === val.type));
            if (versionGroup) {
              versionGroup.versions.push(val)
            } else {
              acc.push({type: val.type, versions: [val]})
            }
            return acc;
          }, []
        )
      ),
    )
```

The key point to understand is that your service is returning you an `Array` of things. In order to achieve your result you can work directly on that `Array` with `Array` methods and you do not need to use `Observable` operators. Please do not consider the code of the grouping logic I have used above as the right implementation - a real implementation probably would benefit in using things like `lodash` for grouping, but I did not want to over complicate things.

This is you original code

```
getData() {
    return this._dataService.getVersions().pipe(
      mergeMap((versions: Array<any>) => versions),
      groupBy((version:IVersion) => version.type),
      mergeMap(group => group.pipe(
        toArray(),
        map(versions=> {
          return {
            type: group.key,
            versions: versions
          }
        }),
        toArray()
      )),
      reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat(v), [])
    )
  }
```

What this does is

1. you create a stream of objects applying the first `mergeMap` to the
   Array returned by the service
2. via `groupBy` operator you create a new Observable which emits the
3. Objects grouped according to your logic then you enter a second more
   complex `mergeMap` which takes the the arrays emitted by `groupBy`,
   turn them into a stream of Objects, just to immediately convert them
   to an Array again via the first `toArray`, that gets then
   transformed to the Object of type {type: string, versions: []}, to
   then eventually invoke again `toArray` to create an Array of Array
4. The last thing you do is to run `reduce` to create your final Array

Why it works only with `take`? Because `groupBy` gets executed only when its source Observable completes, which makes sense you you want to group a finite set of things. Similarly does `reduce` Observable operator.

`take` is a way to complete the source Observable.

Comment: Thanks for this info, this is what I was concerned about. So when I return data from via my socket that should trigger the next() function on my observable right? And does toArray not emit a value upon next()? Ideally I would not use take(1) since I may want to update the data in real-time (which is why I’m using sockets). Is there another method I could use? Maybe without toArray?

Comment: Could it be what @m1ch4ls suggested, that because I have an eager observable it’s emitting before I have actually subscribed to it? I tried using a behaviour subject instead of an observable as I thought that’s meant to always hold the latest value but that didn’t work either..

Comment: Remove `toArray` and just `subscribe` to the Observable which "closes" your socket. `subscribe` allows you to define 3 functions: the first one is the one invoked any time `next` is called, the second is to manage errors, the third is to do something when the Obervable completes.

Comment: I am not sure about eagerness vs laziness in this case. I would tend to think that Observables which close sockets are hot (eager?) by their nature. What happens if you send a message over a socket with no listener attached? It just gets lost. If you subscribe to the socket later, you will receive only the messages sent over the socket from that moment onward. On the contrary, Observables wrapping http requests are lazy since they are not executed until the Observable is subscribed.

Comment: I've created a simple example in stackblitz. How could I edit this to get the same result but without using take(1) so that I can update the data if needed? - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-toarray-problem

Comment: I have updated my answer and edited your example so that now works without the need of using `take`